# JPA use id from nested class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have table in my database

```sql
create table metrics
(
    metric_id   integer,
    time        timestamp,
    workflow_id varchar,
    job_id      varchar,
    name        varchar,
    metric_type   varchar
);
```

And two objects

```java
@Embeddable
public class Metric {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long metricId;
    private OffsetDateTime time;
    private String workflowId;
    private String jobId;
    private String name;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "metrics")
public class CPU {
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private final MetricType metricType = MetricType.CPU;
    @Embedded
    private Metric metric;
}
```

Is it possible to use `@Id` defined in `Metric` class as `@Id` used for `CPU` entity? 
I do not want to create composite key, I just want to use the `@Id` from `Metric` as `@Id` in `CPU`

Comment: What about using `@EmbeddedId`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that what you want to use is discriminator based inheritance:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "metrics")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "metric_type")
public abstract class Metric {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long metricId;
    private OffsetDateTime time;
    private String workflowId;
    private String jobId;
    private String name;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CPU")
public class CPU extends Metric {
}
```